# PHP Tidy removes the closing </head> tag incorrectly

Tags: php, tidy

I was testing my PHP Tidy config one day and found that it fail to process any page from [the guardian](http://www.theguardian.com/uk).

My config is:

```
$tidy_config = array(
    'new-blocklevel-tags' => 'article aside audio figure footer header nav section source track video svg',
    'new-empty-tags' => 'source track',
    'new-inline-tags' => 'audio canvas embed video',
    'wrap' => 0,
    'markup' => false,
);
```

`$tidy->body()` output an empty body, while I notice `$tidy->html()` output does not contain the original `</head>` (which exists in the source), but instead moved it to the end (as if it's added by Tidy itself).

I have tested Guardian front page and some news/column page, same issues. This config works for BBC or other sites in my test, at the very least I don't expect it to return empty `body` or move the closing `head` tag.

Can anyone figure out why?

PS: my Tidy release version is `25 March 2009`, which as far as I know is the *latest release*.

Answer (score 0):

There is a feature request in the Tidy ticket system on Sourceforge requesting support for HTML5. The Guardian page IS using HTML5.

On the other side, I'd say that Tidy is not being actively developed anymore. All the commits into the CVS repository are years old, with the latest commit being in the experimental directory 21 months ago changing something about HTML5. There also is a branch at Github, with the last commit one year ago. https://github.com/w3c/tidy-html5 You could try and compile this.

Comment: While I do know the w3c fork, I don't think this issue is with "Tidy not supporting HTML5", head tag is not HTML5 and doctype should be backward compatible. Also the w3c fork is alarmingly not updated for a year (no reply on issues neither)